# React TS - TypeWriter component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

So I'm still learning React and JavaScript in general. I've been trying to make a TypeWriter effect component. I found a tutorial online for how to make a vanilla JS TypeWriter, I'm trying to convert it into a React component, I've made a start on it trying to convert some of the timing variables into props, but I'm not sure how to get it fully converted and have been struggling.

**Extras:**
I would also like to make it so there is a `prop` for looping the animation indefinitely or just playing it once. For example:
`loop={true}` would make it play indefinitely, if you don't specify this prop is would just animate through the array and then stop on the last word in the array.

Instead of using `classNames`, I'd like to use `styled-components`, this would probably work out better too since there is some dynamic className stuff happening for the blinking cursor animation.

> I'm not sure if the code from this tutorial is the most efficient way
>   of writing this kind of logic so if there's a way of improving it,
>   please let me know. :)

Here's the vanilla JS TypeWriter tutorial [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Coding_Journey/pen/BEMgbX)

Here's currently what I have in my component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface ITypeWriter {
  textArray: Array<string>;
  typingDelay: number;
  erasingDelay: number;
  newTextDelay: number;
}

const TypeWriter: React.FC<ITypeWriter> = ({
  textArray,
  typingDelay,
  erasingDelay,
  newTextDelay
}) => {
  // START - Code from tutorial
  const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");
  const cursorSpan = document.querySelector(".cursor");

  let textArrayIndex = 0;
  let charIndex = 0;

  function type() {
    if (charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
      if (!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing"))
        cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
      typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
      charIndex++;
      setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
    } else {
      cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
      setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
    }
  }

  function erase() {
    if (charIndex > 0) {
      if (!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing"))
        cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
      typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(
        0,
        charIndex - 1
      );
      charIndex--;
      setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
    } else {
      cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
      textArrayIndex++;
      if (textArrayIndex >= textArray.length) textArrayIndex = 0;
      setTimeout(type, typingDelay + 1100);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    if (textArray.length) setTimeout(type, newTextDelay + 250);
  });
  // END - Code from tutorial

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledText>{}</StyledText>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TypeWriter;

const StyledText = styled.span`
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #dd7732;
`;
```

Here's a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-grothendieck-cqbq1), forks are appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to make your life easier: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/ It's better not to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I don't really want to add extra packages to my project, plus I'm not really learning from this. Thanks though :)

Comment: Here's a pure React solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-waterfall-cj263 (don't fix the "error" in the component or the timeout logic breaks)

Comment: Managed to fix the issue, code is error-free now.

Comment: @ChrisG Would you mind commenting your code to explain what you're doing please? Also, please look at the "Extras" part in my question - many thanks! :)

Comment: I added comments and a `loop` prop; as for styled components, that sounds like a nice follow-up task for you, I guess :)

Comment: @ChrisG I mean I definitely would if I know how lol, also could you please remove the blinking cursor once the animation has finished if looping isn't true?

Comment: What's the point of handing you a completely finished component? This isn't a free coding service; you're lucky I spent half an hour creating this in the first place :)

Comment: @ChrisG No no, I very much appreciate your help, I'm just learning as I go :)